# DML Exception and validation rule in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagemessages, dmlexception

Today I had a very unusual experience while working on a VF page. It's a very simple page and controller but the results were quite strange. Actually, I am trying to save an Opportunity and if there is any exception, I am displaying the message on VF page.

I was using this piece of code --> **It was not displaying the page message as it was entering the try block despite hitting a validation rule.**

```
try{
controller.save();
pageref = controller.view();            
system.debug('inside try '+pageref );
}
Catch(Exception e){
ApexPages.addMessages(e);
system.debug('inside catch '+e);
pageref = null;
}
```

As soon as I replaced **controller.save()** by **upsert**, everything became fine. Error messages started to come on the VF page and I could also see the code getting inside catch block.

Can someone explain why such behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I checked everything carefully. When using standardcontroller save, Error is captured inside this method and hence catch block is never executed. 
It's better to do this if using standardcontroller:

```
Pagereference pageref = null;
pageref = controller.save();
if(pageref == null)
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,'ERROR : Please contact the System Admin.'));
```

In case of **upsert**, the error can be easily captured in a catch block.
I would also advise not to use:

```
pageref = controller.view();
```

The url returned from save() method would be enough to handle.